Python typing error when incrementing a dict value: 'Unsupported operand types for + ("object" and "int")'
I have this code:
result = {"AAA": "a", "BBB": "b", "Count": 0}
result["Count"] += 1

mypy generates this error message:
Unsupported operand types for + ("object" and "int")

What are some easy ways to fix this?

Well, how do you want to fix it? Do you want to specify the type of result['Count'] or do you want to ignore the error?

I'm voting to close this question, as it asks for a list of solutions without defining any objective criteria to determine a definitive answer.

You can define the expected shape of the dictionary by defining a TypedDict:
from typing import TypedDict

class ResultDict(TypedDict):
    AAA: str
    BBB: str
    Count: int

result: ResultDict = {"AAA": "a", "BBB": "b", "Count": 0}
result["Count"] += 1

In practice, it's generally easier to use a dataclasses.dataclass when you want to collect different types of data under specific names in a single object in a type-safe way.  The syntax looks different but you get essentially the same functionality:
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Result:
    AAA: str
    BBB: str
    Count: int

result = Result(AAA="a", BBB="b", Count=0)
result.Count += 1


you should define the type of your dict:
from typing import Union, Dict

result: Dict[str, Union[int, str]]


Mypy raise the error as it just check the first value from your dict and determine it as type Dict[str, str]

Dict is deprecated in favor of just using dict, and you can skip the import by writing dict[str, int|str].

This won't fix the error, it'll just change it to complain about adding str and int (since result['Count'] could be a str under that union type).
